# How to algebraically derive the determinant expression for the cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant, cross-product

I was reading this post: [Deriving formula for cross-product.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742326/deriving-formula-for-cross-product) and I understand the derivation there of the formula and it's easy enough to just manually check that the resulting formula is the same as the one we get from taking the determinant of the matrix with the first row being the unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the second two rows being the Cartesian coordinates of the two vectors we're crossing.

But is there a way to derive that determinant expression more directly, perhaps by thinking in terms of linear transformations instead of by solving a system of equations via elimination?

To be clear, I'm aware it's often said that writing the formula as a determinant is an abuse of notation meant only as a mnemonic, and that we aren't *really* taking a determinant.  It's unclear to me why that would be the case though.  I mean, I get that the elements of the top row of the matrix are each members of $\mathbb{R}^3$ while the elements of the second two rows are members of $\mathbb{R}$, which presumably means the matrix is a representation of a linear transformation not on $\mathbb{R}^3$ but on some vector space that's a combination of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}$, right?  But there surely must still be some way to rigorously and directly derive this expression.

Edit: I mean "derive" in the sense of a direct proof (i.e. not a proof by contradiction or one that relies on manually verifying that two expressions happen to be equal).

Comment: I would recommend reading Chapter 10 on determinants of Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra done right.

Comment: For many that formula is **the definition** of the cross product. And you never need to derive a definition, you just use it. First prove that whatever you defined has the properties you subscribed. What is your definition of the cross product?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I've always thought _the definition_ was **A** × **B** = AB • sin(θ) • **n**, where **n** is one of the two unit vectors orthogonal to **A** and **B** picked out by the right-hand rule, and θ is the angle between **A** and **B** which is defined by the dot product formula.

Comment: @blargoner, not really.  It was an interesting read and validated my instinct that the determinant formula is more than an abuse of notation and can be made rigorous.  But it didn't explain how to algebraically _derive_ it, which is what I actually want to know.

Comment: Ok. That is a possibility. But then the determinant formula will give you the wrong result unless you also prescribe that the $xyz$-axes must be oriented in a right-handed way. Something we can do, but really is just a choice. Using the determinant as the definition has the benefit that proving orthogonality and the prescribed length is straight forward, the orientation OTOH is a bit of a pain :-). In other words, from the point of view of teaching linear algebra, using the determinant as a definition is pedagogically simpler.

Comment: For my money, the explanations [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1107764/11619) may be more illuminating. Though that simply uses a different mechanism for handling the orientation question.

Comment: That was an automatically generated comment. But you might have more luck if you edit your post to clarify your seemingly private meaning of the word "derive".