# Intuition behind cross-product and area of parallelogram

Tags: area, exterior-algebra, cross-product

The cross product in 2D is defined like that: $|(x_1, y_1) \times (x_2, y_2)| = x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1.$

I perfectly understand the first part of the definition: $x_1 y_2$, which is simply the area of a rectangle:

[image]

I am struggling to understand the second part: $- x_2 y_1.$
I feel that the second part, probably, has to do with the rotations of the vectors $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, because when we rotate the original rectangle we should preserve the area and $- x_2 y_1$ somehow ***compensates*** for the *excess amount of area* that we get from the first term $x_1 y_2$.

I feel that my intuition lacks a lot of details and I would be grateful for the explanations of the second term and it's connection to the rotations.

---

My question is different from [Reasoning behind the cross products used to find area](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606337/reasoning-behind-the-cross-products-used-to-find-area), although the titles are almost identical. The orthogonality of my question to [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606337/reasoning-behind-the-cross-products-used-to-find-area) can be seen, by reading these parts of [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606337/reasoning-behind-the-cross-products-used-to-find-area):

> I do not have any issues with calculating the area between two vectors.

But I have.

> ...but not why the cross product is used instead of the dot product.

The dot product is out of the scope of my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reasoning behind the cross products used to find area](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606337/reasoning-behind-the-cross-products-used-to-find-area)

Comment: It would be useful an image with $y_1$ and $x_2$ not null.

Comment: The cross product is nothing but the incomplete computation of the (orientated, that is, including sign) volume computed by $\det(\vec x,\vec y, \vec z)$ where $\vec z$ is not specified yet and thus this leves us with a *function* $\det(\vec x,\vec y, \cdot): \vec z\mapsto\det(\vec x, \vec y, \vec z)$.

Comment: @Lovsovs I'd bet this is not the first and only Q&A that could be a duplicate (or, should we better state it, an equivalent)? The core of this has been asked sooo many times that it makes ma fell this is not a problem for "(re)search before posting a question!!!!" but for a lack of a FAQ for those ever repeating questions.

Comment: @GyroGearloose You mean like [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions)?

Comment: @Gyro Thank you for the suggestion. I remember almost all the facts connected to the cross product. Before posting the question I have reread Wikipedia several times and read all the related questions in math.stackexchange. The issue is not that I can't see that the determinant and the cross product are computed identically, but it is in the lack of intuition. How would you develop this concept if you were born in the year 1000?

Comment: @Bye_World Yes, didn't look deep into it, but yes. There are some always repeated questions about *eternal truth* (?!?), and what hurts me most is that they nearly all get low depth answers only repeating *what we all know* without rigid reasoning.

Comment: @Pixar "I have reread Wikipedia several times" ..., don't know for you, but if *I* have to read wikipedia more then once, I don't get more information, only more confusion. As for *science*, wikipedia is sick in more than one aspect. (Don't tempt me to explain in details.)

Comment: @Pixar (jokingly), if I would have be born in 1000, I'd have no choice but to explain it by trinity, or I'd be to burn on the stake. For a more scientific reasoning, to describe a volume, 3 orthogonal vectors are required. The keywords in our time are "volume" and "alternating mulitlinear form", which will also cover higher dimensional cases.

Answer (score 1):

- The formula works fine for the standard unit vectors.
- Stretching one of the vectors by a constant $c$ should multiply the (oriented) area by $c$ and does indeed multiply the cross product by $c$
- Shearing along $(x_1,y_1)$, i.e., replacing $(x_2,y_2)$ with $(x_2+cx_1,y_2+cy_1)$ does not change the area and also does not change the cross product (the extra terms cancel)

As any parallelogram can be obtained from the standard unit vectors by a few steps of shearing/stretching, the cross product tells us the oriented area for all parallelograms.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a geometrical vision, lock at the figure.

[image]

The area of the parallelogram $OMPN$ is obviously the same as the area of the pink parallelogram (same basis $OM$ and same height because the opposite side are parallel). But the area of the pink parallelogram is also given by:$ \quad Area=|a_1c|$ and we can find $c$ as the intersect at the origin of the line from $N,P$.

Whith a bit of elemental analitic geometry you can find that 
$$
c=\frac{a_1b_2-a_2b_1}{a_1}
$$

and this menas that:

$$
Area= |a_1b_2-a_2b_1|
$$

that is the absolute value of the derminat of the matrix that has as columns the two vectors $\overline {OM}$ and $\overline {ON}$ or the absolut value of the cross product of the same two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The cross product can also be defined as $a\times b=|a||b|\sin\theta$, with $\theta$ as the angle between $a$ and $b$.

It can be seen as giving a vector perpendicular to both $a$ and $b$, with length $|a||b|\sin\theta$, or as the area of a skew-rectangle (i.e. a parallelgram) with side lengths $a$ and $b$ and a skew of $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a presentation of the determinant on all-positive quantities which can provide a first-level understanding of the connection with areas. [image: Explanation by area decomposition]